# Differences between crontab root command and normal root command

Tags: python, linux, cron, sudo, raspberry-pi-zero

I have the following `crontab` setup for the root user  (`sudo crontab -e`)

```sh
@reboot cd /home/pi/ && python3 myscript.py 2>&1 >> log.txt
```

The `myscript.py` executes the following command at a given time:

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.call('shutdown -h now', shell=True)
```

The problem is that I get the following error when this command runs as a crontab at reboot:

```sh
/bin/sh: 1: shutdown: not found
```

whereas when I run the following line after logging in as root user:

```sh
cd /home/pi/ && python3 myscript.py 2>&1 >> log.txt
```

all goes fine and the system is shutdown without that error.

Even though I didn't expect it, there seems to be a difference between the way the two commands are executed. Could it be that crontab @reboot somehow has a different context and therefore doesn't behave *exactly* like when a root user executes that command?

Answer (score 1):

Call the following command to find where the `shutdown` binaray is :

```
whereis shutdown
```

On my raspberry, i have the following output :

```
whereis shutdown
shutdown: /sbin/shutdown /usr/share/man/man8/shutdown.8.gz /usr/share/man/man2/shutdown.2.gz
```

Then, change the script call from `shutdown` to the full path to the shutdown binary (for me : `/sbin/shutdown`).

Answer (score 1):

Usually, cron jobs run with a reduced PATH. I would try using an absolute path to `shutdown` in the script.

Comment: shutdown is only one of many shell commands I execute in that script. I also call other scripts that in turn call many other scripts as well. Figuring out all the absolute paths is cumbersome. Isn't there a way to let crontab use the exact same path as when the root user logs in?

Comment: Just export PATH as you need it in the  first script that you start.

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed a missing context; adding PATH to the crontab like this:

```sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

@reboot cd /home/pi/ && python3 myscript.py 2>&1 >> log.txt
```

seems to have fixed the issue.